# dynamoDb range key design for multiple access patterns

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to design a dynamoDb table for my application which has the following relationship:

client has many entities
entity has many channels
channel has a validfrom date

the access patterns that I have are as follows:

- get client and all its entities and all its channels
- get a channel and its parent entity and its parent client if valid from date is after passed in date

since there will be multiple rows with same clientId,EntityId,ChannelID and differing validFromDates I want to make sure that my design will hold up.

access pattern 1 is easy to implement, but for access pattern 2 I have implemented a key in the following format:

- hash key = client id
- range key = entityId | channelId | validFromDate(ticks)

I would like to know if this design is correct and whether there would be any downsides to this design.

[image]